# Android Phone Shell Command Silent Mode?

Tags: shell

What is the shell command to enable/toggle silent mode on an Android phone?

I ask because the Tasker app can run shell commands but only can enable vibration for my specific phone model.

Comment: So you're saying Tasker's Do Not Disturb action doesn't work on your phone? May be try MacroDroid app because without root access there is no point asking for a shell command.

Comment: Tasker only supports Vibrate, it reds out the Silent Mode. I have root access.

Comment: MacroDroid seems to only have Do Not Disturb mode, no Silent mode.

Comment: Silent mode was replaced by Do not Disturb. https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6111295?hl=en Does DND fails to meet your needs?

Comment: Correct, DND doesn't mute mini alarms like those from hourly chimes. Silent Mode still exists in my version--so its weird how Tasker doesn't allow toggling of it in this version..

Answer (score 0):

The settings is supposed to be called `mode_ringer`.

I can read its current status via `adb shell settings get global mode_ringer`.

However, changing its value does not seem to produce any effect and i'm still investigating why...